# Deleting Word text-objects in VIM

Tags: vim

In the expression `(word (first-Word second-Word))` on typing `diW` with the cursor on `f`, I get `(word  second-Word))` when I would like just the Word `first-Word` deleted. On typing `diW` with the cursor on `s` in the original expression, I get `(word (first-Word` when again I would only like the Word removed. I expected the modifier `i` to result in only the Word text-object being deleted and not surrounding spaces or parentheses. How can I get the behavior I want?

Comment: Are you saying you want vim to treat hyphens `-` as a letter for the purposes of deleting a word? (I'm not terribly familiar with vim, but that sounds like what you are trying to accomplish.)

Comment: Yes, that is why I used Word capitalized which refers, in my understanding, to compound words.

Comment: Did you consider `di(`?

Comment: ```di(``` deletes everything between the parentheses. I would like to delete individual Word text-objects without affecting adjacent spaces or parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Uppercase motions like `B`, `E`, `W` move over a sequence of non-blank characters, separated by whitespaces. This can't be changed unless you are willing to remap those keys which i not recommend.

Lowercase motions like `b`, `e`, `w` move over a sequence of characters that are defined by the option `iskeyword`. That means if you add `-` to `iskeyword` with

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

you can achieve your aim by simply pressing `daw` if your cursor is on `f` or `s`.

Alternatively you can invoke

```
setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

if you want the modification of the definition to be local to your buffer.

For further information look at `:h word`.

Comment: I thought that spaces and parentheses were not considered part of the Word text-object. But I could use the approach you suggested by adding additional delimiters like ```_``` to ```iskeyword```, but it seems like I would be losing some of the differences between the word and Word text-objects in other contexts.

Comment: since `iskeyword` is a local option you can use different definitions of `iskeyword` in different buffers